# Web Server Log analyzer from a security perspective

Tags: security, logging, apache-2.4, log-files, ibm-midrange

Web Server Log analyzers are really meant to just show trends, statistics and are more geared towards an SEO/Marketing standpoint.  How can I do the following in regards to HTTP(s) traffic from a security standpoint?:

1. Flag suspicious request (such as common SQL injection techniques, /wp-admin type of activity, or X request per Y time period)
2. Filter for the activity of a particular IP so you can easily follow
   what the user did while visiting your site. (more to track their requests to see if the suspicious request from above was a coincidence or intentional)
3. Option to filter out requests for image/css/js files.

What is the Type of software called which does this? And what types of things should I Google/look in to?

Comment: I think you need to write your own.  Write something that recognises the requests you expect to get, and then what's left is suspicious.  Note that requests for e.g. `foo.php.jpeg` are very suspicious.

Comment: The class of tools you're looking for is called 'web intrusion detection'  Google that.  'Web application firewall' is also relevant.

Comment: Thank you @mc0e .  I don't know if you can post an answer for me to accept due to this question being on hold.  But if you can, I would accept it.  I tried rewording the question so it no longer on hold, but I don't know if EEAA just didn't get to it or if the change wasn't good enough.  I would appreciate some feedback on my change.